# "Are you a Human" message misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Look at our [Captcha page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/captcha)

[image]

Now look at Meta.stackoverflow.com:

[image]

The widths of the Captcha/image container and the Are you a human being? message combined are just a bit wider than the containing box on UX (and [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/captcha)) so instead of floating right next to the captcha box it gets stuck under it.

Shrinking the .mainbar-captcha class' width slightly smaller fixes it, like this:

> .mainbar-captcha { width: 600px !important;}

English has slightly more problems:
[image]

Comment: we're looking into this. Apparently it's broken on several other sites too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed on production.